# Java Spring MVC Project external database configuration with .properties file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, spring-jdbc

I am trying external configuration with properties file. dataSource bean is defined in security-context-xml file and hibernate.cfg.xml use them for database informations and sessionFactory.
I want externally dataSource configuration with encrypted password.

Used code following:

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:sample.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation"
        value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

And sample.properties file is:

jdbc.url="*****"

jdbc.username="****"

jdbc.password="****"

This didn't work and throws exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL '${jdbc.url}'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2023)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1897)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: did you add the oracle driver?

Comment: yes i add in  dataSource bean as    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />

Comment: i meand the library

Comment: yes, com.oracle version 12 is defined in pom.xml file

Comment: looks like it is not included in your project

Comment: Where is the `sample.properties` located? Also remove the `ignore-unresolvable="true"` as you really want to stop your application from loading if the placeholders cannot be resolved.

Comment: sample.properties and hibernate.cfg.xml files in src folder and my classpath is src.